# Temporarily unbind draggable/mouse wheel from zoom/pan map?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, zooming, draggable

I have a page with a zoom/pan map plugin and the zoom/pan works just fine. My problem is that the dialogs are no longer draggable. I've narrowed it down to commenting this line out:

```
$('#imageFullScreen').smartZoom({'containerClass':'zoomableContainer'});
```

and the dialogs will move again. I believe it has to do with the fact that the map is using draggable and I wanted to know if there is some way to unbind the draggable functionality from the map on dialog open, and restore it on dialog close. I do not want to destroy the map, as the user may need to go right back to what they were doing. I have a working demo here http://jsfiddle.net/h4c6a/ and please excuse the fact that I had to copy/paste the entire plug in. I couldn't get it working otherwise. This is the zoom/pan plug in I'm using http://www.jqueryscript.net/zoom/Smart-jQuery-Pan-Zoom-Plugin-Smart-jQuery-Zoom.html Thanks in advance.

Comment: there are 8 errors in your fiddle. open debugger to see them. (Ctrl+maj+i in chrome, F12 in IE, FF). edit : no in fact you have 17 errors once JQueryUI is activated (needed for dragging)

Comment: And, as you can see, it works with JQuery and JQuery UI matching versions. And, as you have pasted all the smartzoom code in the fiddle, I have removed the external link. http://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/h4c6a/2/   . Ho... my bad, the zoom is broken.

Comment: This fiddle does not emulate my solution. This breaks the map functionality completely. In theory, I would like to manipulate the changes outside of the actual script as well, and not have to change the js if possible. I need the pan/zoom to work on the map prior to opening the dialog, then switch to moving the dialog, and back to the map on close. I noticed the close icon on the dialog header is off with your changes as well. http://jsfiddle.net/h4c6a/10/

Comment: Forget about the cross... It's just that you have 2 versions of JQueryUI loaded and only one css. Remove UI in your external resources ad you will see the cross. Anyway, the problem might come from smartZoom. If I deactivate `.dialog()` or don't load UI, the zoom is still broken. http://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/h4c6a/12/

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the code of smartZoom...

```
function mouseDownHandler(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default browser drag
    ... ... ...
    smartData.moveCurrentPosition = new Point(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    smartData.moveLastPosition =  new Point(e.pageX, e.pageY);
}
```

So, Here it is with the correction : http://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/h4c6a/24/

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    dragStart:function( event, ui ) {document.ondragstart = function () { return true; };}
});
```

Dragging the dialog, it reactivate the default dragging behaviour. Best is to set it disable on drag stop... I let you do this.